# Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory without "one-to-one correspondence"(bijection)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know little about theory , what I learnt about is that Cantor used the  "one-to-one correspondence"(bijection) as an axiom to develop the set theory.

I wonder

1) are the axiom of choice and Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory based on "one-to-one correspondence"(bijection)?

2) will the axiom of choice and Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory be still correct(valid) if set theory without  "one-to-one correspondence"(bijection)?

Comment: @Henning: Fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

A one-to-one correspondence is simply a particular kind of function; it can no more be an axiom than it can be an elephant. You may be thinking of the way that we, following Cantor, define what it means for two sets to have the same cardinality: $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if and only if there is a bijection between them. This is simply a definition. It is made within $\mathsf{ZF}$ set theory (and others); it is not a prerequisite for that theory.

Comment: Do you mean the axiom of choice and Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory are not based on "one-to-one correspondence"(bijection)?

Comment: @iMath: I mean that that statement doesn’t even make sense. I can’t assign any meaning to it: the notion of bijection simply isn’t the sort of thing that can be a basis for a theory.

Comment: thanks! what do you mean by "It is made within ZF set theory (and others)"?

Comment: @iMath ZF(C) is a theory in a very limited language - the only symbol it has "a priori" besides those of first-order logic is "$\in$". When we speak of "cardinality" in ZFC, we're using *abbreviations* for complicated formulas in the language of ZFC. For example, we can express "$A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality" using just "$\in$", but it's surprisingly difficult (for one thing, we have to define *functions* using just "$\in$," which leads to [some tedium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory)). (cont'd)

Comment: In general, let's say you have a theory of sets, and you want to talk about some concept (say, cardinality) inside that theory. If the language of that theory already contains all the relevant symbols, then great! Otherwise you have to do some work, and show that you can actually define the relevant concepts in the limited language of your theory. Incidentally, based on this and your other question I suggest looking at the [ZFC axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) in detail to see exactly what they consist of.

Answer (score -1):

A bit of historical context might clarify things here.  From the Greeks (Plato, Euclid, etc) onward the question was raised: What does size mean, if anything, for infinity?  People usually came up with arguments which led them to conclude that the concept of 'different sizes of infinity' is nonsense.  This is one aspect which led Aristotle to insist that the only meaningful infinity is *potential* infinity.

Here's an important example: In one of his Dialogues, Galileo observed the relationships between the natural numbers and their squares.  He applied two criteria which 'obviously' determine relative size.  One was *bijection*: For each natural number there is a unique natural square, and conversely, which suggests that the 'number of numbers' is the same as the 'number of squares'.  The other was *containment*, expressed in Euclid's Elements by the common notion 'the whole is greater than the part'.  Since nearly all numbers are *not* squares, and in fact the squares come more and more sparsely as the numbers get larger, this suggests that there are 'many more' numbers than squares.  This inconsistency leads Galilieo to conclude that the concept 'number of numbers' is meaningless.

What Cantor did was to take a radical break with tradition and *abandon* the concept of containment as a determinant of size, relying on *bijection alone*.  This led him to his famous arguments establishing that infinity (or at least *mathematical* infinity) did indeed come in more than one size.  And he was able to back that choice with enough interesting and powerful results that mathematics ultimately *had* to embrace it.

Comment: Your answer may be not helpful to this question, but thanks anyway , and I think your answer is more related to my another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939513/one-to-one-correspondencebijection-and-the-size-of-two-infinite-sets